# @Html.Label won't allow string concatenation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm building dynamic forms based on a partial view. My view inherits a model with a single property: `CatalogName { get; set; }`.

I have tried this:

```
@Html.Label(Model.CatalogName + "-ProductNumber", "Product Number")
@Html.TextBox(Model.CatalogName + "-ProductNumber")
```

The HTML renders like this though:

```
<label for>Product Number</label>
<input name="CatatalogName-ProductNumber" type="text" />
```

If I write my code like this:

```
@Html.Label("ProductNumber-" + Model.CatalogName", "Product Number")
```

It will render the way I expect

```
<label for="ProductNumber-CatalogName">Product Number</label>
```

Is this a bug with MVC? Are there any answers as to why my concatenation won't work the way I want it  to in the label, but works fine with the TextBox?

My model looks like this:

```
public class Product
{
  public string CatalogName { get; set; }
}
```

My partial view inherits the model:

```
@model Models.Product
```

My controller renders an action result like this:

```
return PartialView("_webForm", Models.Product { CatalogName = "CatalogName"} );
```

Comment: It appears, based on your code, that the `@Html.TextBox()` is not outputting the `id` attribute - which is what `for` uses. This doesn't appear to be a problem with the latest version of MVC (RC2 i think) - what version are you using?

Comment: Awesome icon btw, one of my favorite series of games :)

Comment: I am using MVC 3 RC2. I didn't notice that my ID is not outputting, but you're right. When I just specify a string "ProductNumber" then both id and name are present.

Are you able to add a label or textbox with a dynamic value and have it populate correctly?

Comment: I copied your code exactly for the first part that you say produces invalid output - and it produces valid output here. What type is `CatalogName` (I assumed string in my sample model)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your Model.CatalogName contain a period? I stumbled across this question while noticing they don't render anything before a period in the string.

Comment: I don't think our CatalogName ever contained a period. It's been a while now, and I've since left the company. 

Thinking about it, there's a good chance that a catalog name had a hyphen though, perhaps that has a similar effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to stumble across this thread while searching for a similar issue. I found the source code that Microsoft (surprisingly) provides, and found at least my issue.

Because the comments for the parameters are not clear, I was using the method incorrectly. I was just looking for a simple way to display some text. The first parameter should be the ID of the corresponding control to which the Label is created. The SECOND parameter is what will actually display in the displaying section of the label.

So with a call of `@Html.Label(parameter1)`, you will get `<label for="parameter1">parameter1</label>`.

Because the ID begins with a "." in javascript and jQuery calls, the underlying code only takes the last section of `parameter1` after the final ".".

What I just wound up doing was creating my own @Html.Span extension method to allow me to accomplish what I was looking for. I understand this doesn't exactly answer MrGrigg's question, but I hope someone else who finds this could find it useful.

Here is the code that all of the @Html.Label methods call:

```
internal static MvcHtmlString LabelHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, string htmlFieldName, string labelText = null) {
        string resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText)) {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
        return tag.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. The problem was that I wasn't getting the results I wanted out of the built in methods. At the time I had no idea about building helpers like this, so I think this is great. Thanks for coming by and helping our futures selves.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Label(Model.CatalogName.ToString() + "-ProductNumber", "Product Number")

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define a method or a property in the model class that does the concatenation.

If that is not an option, try:

```
@Html.Label((Model.CatalogName + "-ProductNumber").ToString(), "Product Number")
```

Comment: Nothing works and now I'm sad. Thanks for offering suggestions though. I'll just wait for the RTM release and perhaps that will either fix the glitch or repair whatever is wrong in my install that isn't allowing it to work.